# What is the technique to get a proper consistent crochet tension without being too tight?

Tags: crocheting

Crochet tension is a real problem for me. In order to keep it even I have a very tight stitch meaning I have to go up in hook size to get the correct tension for the piece.

Is there a technique that I am missing to get a proper consistent tension without being too tight?

Comment: I find I run into this problem when I start a new project with a new yarn. I have found that as I work more and more through the project that I get into a rhythm, and I stop getting uneven tension. This isn't meant to be an answer but I hope it provides a little assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem does not seem so strange to me: I do the same with needles whenever I knit. That is the main reason why instructions contain the **Gauge** part, so you can choose the right yarn and hook to get the right size.

As I found written on a shawl crochet pattern:

> CHECK YOUR GAUGE.
>
> Use any size hook to obtain the gauge.

On the other hand, don't be too worried about "even" stitches while crocheting at first, but let the thread slide quite easily through your fingers while you work, otherwise the final result will be too stiff. The more you get used to crocheting, the more regular your stitches will become.

Hope this can help!

Answer (score -1):

As Lucia already stated, practising helps a lot. 
Then, there are different ways to hold your yarn, try and find the way that works best for you.
Take a look at 
http://www.crochetguru.com/hold-yarn-for-crochet.html
for images and instructions.

One way to hold the yarn, is loop the yarn around your little finger, then over your ringfinger, middle finger and index finger.

A loose way to hold your yarn is without the loop around your little finger, just the thread betweeen little finger and ringfinger, and over your ringfinger, middle finger and index finger. 
If that's too loose, you could loop the thread around your index finger.

Comment: Hi! This is essentially a link-only answer. Can you try to include some specific examples from the website you linked? That way if the website goes down, we still have the information here.

Comment: This is definitely a trap that we don't want to fall into! We are a site that is here to help people. We are not a site to redirect people to other sites to get help. These websites often die and, with them, the answer becomes useless. For info on low quality answers, check out this question on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: You're definitely right. I've added extra info.